# how to avoid inconsistency in neural network outputs

Tags: r, neural-network, forecasting, trading

I coded a forecast of the price of bitcoin is generated according to parameters with indicators, I have daily price data. Every time I try to regenerate a result the neural network generates new results, I fix this by putting two seeds which help me parameterize the initial weights of the network, the thing is that I need the results to give me a positive return and this is done Some seeds meet and others do not, I would like to know if there is a way to preserve the positive results of the neural network avoiding overfitting, or if the code simply does not have positive reproducibility in another database.

I am trying to ensure that the code I generate results in other databases such as not only bitcoin but other assets, in addition to that not only a period of time but in several periods of time, but every time I move the seed these results change abruptly. I would like to know if there is a way to optimize the initial weights in order to maximize the return of the neural network without leaving the rmse behind.

```
install.packages("TTR")
install.packages("caret")
install.packages("nnet")

## Loading the Dataset
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/scarl/OneDrive/Escritorio/Thesis/Code_PF/Data/Bitcoin.csv", header = TRUE, dec = ".")
price <- data$Close
HLC <- matrix(c(data$High, data$Low, data$Close), nrow = length(data$High))

##Calculating the log returns

bitcoin.lr <- diff(log(price))

## Loading the technical indicators selected for modeling
library(TTR)
set.seed(44)
rsi <- RSI(price)
MACD <- MACD(price)
macd <- MACD[, 1]
will <- williamsAD(HLC)
cci <- CCI(HLC)
STOCH <- stoch(HLC)
stochK <- STOCH[, 1]
stochD <- STOCH[, 1]

## Input and Target matrix for training and validation dataset
Input <- matrix(c(rsi[55:294], cci[55:294], macd[55:294], will[55:294], stochK[55:294], stochD[55:294]), nrow = 240)
Target <- matrix(c(bitcoin.lr[56:295]), nrow = 240)
trainingdata <- cbind(Input, Target)
colnames(trainingdata) <- c("RSI", "CCI", "MACD", "WILL", "STOCHK", "STOCHD", "Return")

##Splitting the learning dataset in a 90-10% (train-validation) ratio
library(caret)

set.seed(44)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(bitcoin.lr[56:295], p = .9, list = FALSE)
bitcoin.train <- trainingdata[trainIndex, ]
bitcoin.test <- trainingdata[-trainIndex, ]

## Feed-forward neural networks with a single hidden layer
library(nnet)

best.network <- matrix(c(5, 0.5))
best.rmse <- 1

set.seed(44)
for (i in 1:6)
  for (j in 1:5) {
    bitcoin.fit <- nnet(Return ~ RSI + CCI + MACD + WILL + STOCHK + STOCHD,
                        data = bitcoin.train, maxit = 1000, size = i, decay = 0.001 * j, linout = 1)
    bitcoin.predict <- predict(bitcoin.fit, newdata = bitcoin.test)
    bitcoin.rmse <- sqrt(mean((bitcoin.predict - bitcoin.lr[272:295])^2))
    if (bitcoin.rmse < best.rmse) {
      best.network[1, 1] <- i
      best.network[2, 1] <- j
      best.rmse <- bitcoin.rmse
    }
  }

## Input and Target matrix for the test dataset
InputTest <- matrix(c(rsi[295:324], cci[295:324], macd[295:324], will[295:324], stochK[295:324], stochD[295:324]), nrow = 30)
TargetTest <- matrix(c(bitcoin.lr[296:325]), nrow = 30)
Testdata <- cbind(InputTest, TargetTest)
colnames(Testdata) <- c("RSI", "CCI", "MACD", "WILL", "STOCHK", "STOCHD", "Return")

## We fit the best neural network model on test data
bitcoin.fit <- nnet(Return ~ RSI + CCI + MACD + WILL + STOCHK + STOCHD,
                    data = bitcoin.train, maxit = 1000, size = best.network[1, 1],
                    decay = 0.001 * best.network[2, 1], linout = 1)
bitcoin.predict1 <- predict(bitcoin.fit, newdata = Testdata)


## We repeat and average the model 20 times to eliminate the outlier networks
for (i in 1:20) {
  bitcoin.fit <- nnet(Return ~ RSI + CCI + MACD + WILL + STOCHK + STOCHD, data = bitcoin.train,
                      maxit = 1000, size = best.network[1, 1], decay = 0.001 * best.network[2, 1], linout = 1)
  bitcoin.predict <- predict(bitcoin.fit, newdata = Testdata)
  bitcoin.predict1 <- (bitcoin.predict1 + bitcoin.predict) / 2
}

## We calculate the result of the buy-and-hold benchmark strategy and neural network on the test dataset
money <- money2 <- matrix(0, 31)
money[1, 1] <- money2[1, 1] <- 100

for (i in 2:31) {
  direction1 <- ifelse(bitcoin.predict1[i - 1] < 0, -1, 1)
  direction2 <- ifelse(TargetTest[i - 1] < 0, -1, 1)
  money[i, 1] <- ifelse((direction1 - direction2) == 0,
                        money[i - 1, 1] * (1 + abs(TargetTest[i - 1])),
                        money[i - 1, 1] * (1 - abs(TargetTest[i - 1])))
  money2[i, 1] <- 100 * (price[294 + i - 1] / price[294])
}

## We plot the investment value according to the benchmark and the neural network strategy on the test dataset (1 month)
x <- 1:31
matplot(cbind(money, money2), type = "l", xaxt = "n", ylab = "", col = c("black", "grey"), lty = 1)
legend("bottomleft", legend = c("Neural network", "Benchmark"), pch = 19, col = c("black", "grey"))
axis(1, at = c(1, 10, 20, 30), lab = c("2022-01-01", "2022-04-08", "2022-07-15", "2022-10-21"))
box()
mtext(side = 1, "Test dataset", line = 2)
mtext(side = 2, "Investment value", line = 2)
```

Comment: If you are asking about statistical or machine learning theory and/or procedures and not explicitly about coding you may consider asking it over on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)